# How to avoid 2d enemy using trigonometry?

Tags: path-finding, html5, trigonometry

I'm making a game in Javascript & HTML5.

I have a "bullet" (let's call it so) that needs to reach the enemy (at fixed position) and that need to avoid the enemy's "bullet".

To make the bullet move to the enemy i'm using this code:

```
var direction = Math.atan2(self.enemy.y - self.y, self.enemy.x - self.x);
var dir_diff = self.rotation - direction;
// ... other code
self.rotation -= dir_diff;
self.x += Math.cos(self.rotation) * self.speed / dt;
self.y += Math.sin(self.rotation) * self.speed / dt;
```

How can I make the bullet avoid another moving bullet?

I tried to search but algorithms like A* etc. doesn't seem right for this.

Thank you.

Comment: i'd try to raycast from -30º to 30º and simply turn to the opposite direction when a enemy thing is detected

Comment: Can there be more than one enemy bullet? Also, how far do you want the avoidance radius to be? And do you need a perfect solution (enemy bullet is not touched no matter what) or is a "good enough" solution sufficient (tries its best to avoid but might still hit it when the player is relying too much on it)? And does the other bullet have that same dodging behavior?

Comment: @Philipp yes, there can be more than one enemy, however I think that avoiding one si a "good enough" solution. It doesn't have to be perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* Detect nearest enemy */
for (var i = 0; i < nears.length; i++) {
    /* self.void is an array containing the types of objects I want to avoid */
    if (self.avoid.indexOf(nears[i].type) > -1 && nears[i] != self) {
        var dist = Math_distance(nears[i].x, nears[i].y, self.x, self.y);
        if (dist > self.avoidRadius) continue;
        if (dist < near_dist || near_dist == null) {
            near_i = i;
            near_dist = dist;
        }
    }
}

if (near_i != null) {

    var avoid_direction = Math.atan2(nears[near_i].y - self.y, nears[near_i].x - self.x);
    var avoid_diff = self.rotation - avoid_direction + Math.PI;
    if (avoid_diff > Math.PI / 5) {
        avoid_diff = Math.PI / 5;
    }
    if (avoid_diff < -Math.PI / 5) {
        avoid_diff = -Math.PI / 5;
    }

    /* Delta, frame rate */
    avoid_diff /= dt;

    /* Strength of the avoid force */
    var strength = 1 / near_dist * 100;

    dir_diff += avoid_diff * self.avoidForce * strength * self.avoidSign;
}
```

Thanks to PRDeving for the idea of "steering".
This works for me.